# Maintain position after animation in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have 2 object unity animations. Both affect different parameters (the first moves from point A to point B, the second color). The first animation should work first, then the second. But as soon as the second animation starts, the position of the object is reset to point A

I tried to add position keys to point B in animation 2 in the first and last frame. But when animation 2 starts, the object moves to point A for a moment and then to point B (jerking)

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest you to not use animation. Rather use transform.position to move the object from one place to another. You can also use lerp is this regard.

```
    void Update() {
      float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
```

2. You can also use `Getcomponent<MeshRendere>().material.color = Color.defineyourcolor` to change the color of the object.

Comment: Animations in the project are much more complex and this solution will not work. On the example of these two animations, I only described the question